# In matlab, we calculate inv(A)* B by A\B. How about Julia? note that A&B are two large sparse matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, julia, sparse-matrix, matrix-inverse

Does anybody have experience with the calculation of inv(A)*B in Julia, where A and B are large sparse matrices?

When I used zz = A\B in Julia. It shows the following error in Julia.
[Image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wktBM.png)

```
MethodError: no method matching ldiv!(::SuiteSparse.UMFPACK.UmfpackLU{Float64,Int64}, ::SparseArrays.SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64})
Closest candidates are:
  ldiv!(!Matched::Number, ::AbstractArray) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\LinearAlgebra\src\generic.jl:152
  ldiv!(!Matched::LinearAlgebra.LU{T,LinearAlgebra.Tridiagonal{T,V}}, ::Union{AbstractArray{T,2}, AbstractArray{T,1}} where T) where {T, V} at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\LinearAlgebra\src\lu.jl:523
  ldiv!(!Matched::LinearAlgebra.Transpose{#s617,#s616} where #s616<:LinearAlgebra.LU{T,LinearAlgebra.Tridiagonal{T,V}} where #s617, ::Union{AbstractArray{T,2}, AbstractArray{T,1}} where T) where {T, V} at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\LinearAlgebra\src\lu.jl:555
  ...

Stacktrace:
 [1] \(::SuiteSparse.UMFPACK.UmfpackLU{Float64,Int64}, ::SparseArrays.SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64}) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\LinearAlgebra\src\factorization.jl:87
 [2] \(::SparseArrays.SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64}, ::SparseArrays.SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64}) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.2\SparseArrays\src\linalg.jl:1374
 [3] top-level scope at In[5]:1
```

Comment: Perhaps take a look at https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/19500#issuecomment-264908879

Comment: Hi Nitish, can you provide a reproducible example, where you initialize `A` and `B` and run `zz=A\B`?  It would also be useful to post the version of Julia that you are using.  Thank you!

Comment: On julia 1.3 at least you can't take the inv of a sparse matrix, because there's a risk it will kill the memory

Comment: @kmsquire: I have added the screenshot for reference. Thank you :).

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard : For this reason, I am using A\B format (LU Decomposition). However, It is not working in sparse matrix case (Julia 1.2). I am wondering if I should use iterative approach or call python library.

Comment: @nitish please do not share code as screen shots.

Comment: Also a MWE which does not include loading anything from files